# JBoss [ClassLoaderManager] Unexpected err... cannot access superclass?

Tags: jboss, jackson, jboss6.x

Trying to deploy to JBoss-6.0.0.Final container and have been battling the following stacktrace.  Maybe there's a known solution??

```
14:36:08,218 INFO  [AbstractJBossASServerBase] Server Configuration:

    JBOSS_HOME URL: file:/E:/java/jboss-6.0.0.Final/
    Bootstrap: $JBOSS_HOME\server/default/conf/bootstrap.xml
    Common Base: $JBOSS_HOME\common/
    Common Library: $JBOSS_HOME\common/lib/
    Server Name: default
    Server Base: $JBOSS_HOME\server/
    Server Library: $JBOSS_HOME\server/default/lib/
    Server Config: $JBOSS_HOME\server/default/conf/
    Server Home: $JBOSS_HOME\server/default/
    Server Data: $JBOSS_HOME\server/default/data/
    Server Log: $JBOSS_HOME\server/default/log/
    Server Temp: $JBOSS_HOME\server/default/tmp/

14:36:08,234 INFO  [AbstractServer] Starting: JBossAS [6.0.0.Final "Neo"]
14:36:13,375 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java version: 1.6.0_13,Sun Microsystems Inc.
14:36:13,390 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_13-b03)
14:36:13,390 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 11.3-b02,Sun Microsystems Inc.
14:36:13,390 INFO  [ServerInfo] OS-System: Windows XP 5.1,x86
14:36:13,390 INFO  [ServerInfo] VM arguments: -Djboss.home=E:\java\jboss-6.0.0.Final -Djava.library.path=E:\eclipse\genuitec\common\binary\com.sun.java.jdk.win32.x86_1.6.0.013\bin -Djava.endorsed.dirs=E:\java\jboss-6.0.0.Final\lib\endorsed -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m 
14:36:13,453 INFO  [JMXKernel] Legacy JMX core initialized
14:36:38,250 INFO  [AbstractServerConfig] JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 3.4.1.GA
14:36:40,000 INFO  [JSFImplManagementDeployer] Initialized 3 JSF configurations: [Mojarra-1.2, MyFaces-2.0, Mojarra-2.0]
14:36:53,953 WARNING [FileConfigurationParser] AIO wasn't located on this platform, it will fall back to using pure Java NIO. If your platform is Linux, install LibAIO to enable the AIO journal
14:37:40,218 WARN  [ClassLoaderManager] Unexpected error during load of:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.impl.ObjectArraySerializer: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.impl.ObjectArraySerializer cannot access its superclass org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.ArraySerializers$AsArraySerializer
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [:1.6.0_13]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621) [:1.6.0_13]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.access$200(BaseClassLoader.java:52) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:650) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:609) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.6.0_13]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:608) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:585) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseDelegateLoader.loadClass(BaseDelegateLoader.java:156) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.filter.FilteredDelegateLoader.doLoadClass(FilteredDelegateLoader.java:141) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.filter.FilteredDelegateLoader.loadClass(FilteredDelegateLoader.java:132) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoadingTask$ThreadTask.run(ClassLoadingTask.java:461) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.nextTask(ClassLoaderManager.java:262) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.process(ClassLoaderManager.java:161) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:260) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:1152) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassFromDomain(BaseClassLoader.java:886) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.doLoadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:505) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:450) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252) [:1.6.0_13]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320) [:1.6.0_13]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_13]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247) [:1.6.0_13]
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl.resolveComplexTypeInfo(IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl.java:458) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl.getTypeInfo(IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl.java:414) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.IntrospectionTypeInfoFactory.getTypeInfo(IntrospectionTypeInfoFactory.java:54) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.config.plugins.AbstractConfiguration.getTypeInfo(AbstractConfiguration.java:121) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.config.AbstractKernelConfig.getTypeInfo(AbstractKernelConfig.java:95) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.config.AbstractKernelConfigurator.getTypeInfo(AbstractKernelConfigurator.java:102) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.ConfiguratorReflectProvider.getTypeInfo(ConfiguratorReflectProvider.java:47) [:1.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.CachingReflectProvider.getTypeInfo(CachingReflectProvider.java:52) [:1.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.ReflectResourceVisitor.getTypeInfo(ReflectResourceVisitor.java:60) [:1.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.ReflectResourceVisitor.getClassInfo(ReflectResourceVisitor.java:72) [:1.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.ReflectResourceVisitor.doVisit(ReflectResourceVisitor.java:107) [:1.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.ReflectResourceVisitor.visit(ReflectResourceVisitor.java:86) [:1.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.scanning.hierarchy.plugins.HierarchyIndexScanningPlugin.visit(HierarchyIndexScanningPlugin.java:91) [:1.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.scanning.spi.helpers.ScanningPluginWrapper.visit(ScanningPluginWrapper.java:112) [:1.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloading.plugins.visitor.FederatedResourceVisitor.visit(FederatedResourceVisitor.java:101) [jboss-classloading.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloading.plugins.vfs.VFSResourceVisitor.visit(VFSResourceVisitor.java:264) [jboss-classloading-vfs.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:408) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:410) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:410) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:410) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:410) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:410) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:410) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:396) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloading.plugins.vfs.VFSResourceVisitor.visit(VFSResourceVisitor.java:102) [jboss-classloading-vfs.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.classloader.VFSDeploymentClassLoaderPolicyModule.visit(VFSDeploymentClassLoaderPolicyModule.java:181) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.DeploymentUnitScanner.scan(DeploymentUnitScanner.java:111) [:1.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.scanning.spi.helpers.UrlScanner.scan(UrlScanner.java:96) [:1.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.scanning.deployers.ScanningDeployer.deploy(ScanningDeployer.java:95) [:1.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(ProfileDeployAction.java:151) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installActionInternal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper$BasicProfileActivation.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:190) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:87) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activateProfile(ProfileActivationService.java:215) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate(ProfileActivationService.java:159) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.activate(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:112) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.resolver.BasicResolverFactory$ProfileResolverFacade.deploy(BasicResolverFactory.java:87) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.start(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:91) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:132) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:56) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:827) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-5]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:417) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [:1.6.0_13]

14:37:40,250 WARN  [ClassLoaderManager] Unexpected error during load of:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.impl.ObjectArraySerializer: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.impl.ObjectArraySerializer cannot access its superclass org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.ArraySerializers$AsArraySerializer
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [:1.6.0_13]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621) [:1.6.0_13]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.access$200(BaseClassLoader.java:52) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:650) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:609) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.6.0_13]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:608) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:585) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseDelegateLoader.loadClass(BaseDelegateLoader.java:156) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.filter.FilteredDelegateLoader.doLoadClass(FilteredDelegateLoader.java:141) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.filter.FilteredDelegateLoader.loadClass(FilteredDelegateLoader.java:132) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoadingTask$ThreadTask.run(ClassLoadingTask.java:461) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.nextTask(ClassLoaderManager.java:262) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.process(ClassLoaderManager.java:161) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:260) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:1152) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassFromDomain(BaseClassLoader.java:886) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.doLoadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:505) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:450) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252) [:1.6.0_13]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320) [:1.6.0_13]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_13]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247) [:1.6.0_13]
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl.resolveComplexTypeInfo(IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl.java:458) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl.getTypeInfo(IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl.java:414) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.IntrospectionTypeInfoFactory.getTypeInfo(IntrospectionTypeInfoFactory.java:54) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.config.plugins.AbstractConfiguration.getTypeInfo(AbstractConfiguration.java:121) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.config.AbstractKernelConfig.getTypeInfo(AbstractKernelConfig.java:95) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.config.AbstractKernelConfigurator.getTypeInfo(AbstractKernelConfigurator.java:102) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.ConfiguratorReflectProvider.getTypeInfo(ConfiguratorReflectProvider.java:47) [:1.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.CachingReflectProvider.getTypeInfo(CachingReflectProvider.java:52) [:1.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.ReflectResourceVisitor.getTypeInfo(ReflectResourceVisitor.java:60) [:1.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.ReflectResourceVisitor.getClassInfo(ReflectResourceVisitor.java:72) [:1.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.ReflectResourceVisitor.doVisit(ReflectResourceVisitor.java:107) [:1.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.ReflectResourceVisitor.visit(ReflectResourceVisitor.java:86) [:1.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.scanning.annotations.plugins.AnnotationsScanningPlugin.visit(AnnotationsScanningPlugin.java:89) [:1.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.scanning.spi.helpers.ScanningPluginWrapper.visit(ScanningPluginWrapper.java:112) [:1.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloading.plugins.visitor.FederatedResourceVisitor.visit(FederatedResourceVisitor.java:101) [jboss-classloading.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloading.plugins.vfs.VFSResourceVisitor.visit(VFSResourceVisitor.java:264) [jboss-classloading-vfs.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:408) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:410) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:410) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:410) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:410) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:410) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:410) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:396) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloading.plugins.vfs.VFSResourceVisitor.visit(VFSResourceVisitor.java:102) [jboss-classloading-vfs.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.classloader.VFSDeploymentClassLoaderPolicyModule.visit(VFSDeploymentClassLoaderPolicyModule.java:181) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.DeploymentUnitScanner.scan(DeploymentUnitScanner.java:111) [:1.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.scanning.spi.helpers.UrlScanner.scan(UrlScanner.java:96) [:1.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.scanning.deployers.ScanningDeployer.deploy(ScanningDeployer.java:95) [:1.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(ProfileDeployAction.java:151) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installActionInternal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper$BasicProfileActivation.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:190) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:87) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activateProfile(ProfileActivationService.java:215) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate(ProfileActivationService.java:159) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.activate(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:112) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.resolver.BasicResolverFactory$ProfileResolverFacade.deploy(BasicResolverFactory.java:87) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.start(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:91) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:132) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:56) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:827) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-5]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:417) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [:1.6.0_13]

14:38:57,531 WARNING [FileConfigurationParser] AIO wasn't located on this platform, it will fall back to using pure Java NIO. If your platform is Linux, install LibAIO to enable the AIO journal
14:38:58,234 INFO  [JMXConnector] starting JMXConnector on host 127.0.0.1:1090
14:38:58,812 INFO  [MailService] Mail Service bound to java:/Mail
14:39:00,937 INFO  [HornetQServerImpl] live server is starting..
```

Seems to be a lib conflict with:  **org.codehaus.jackson**.map.ser.ArraySerializers 
..but I don't see the jackson lib in jboss/common/lib.

Where's the conflict coming from?

I've tried the following declaration in jboss-classloading.xml to no avail.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<classloading xmlns="urn:jboss:classloading:1.0"
    name="ROOT.war"
    domain="WebDomain"
    excluded="bsh,org.codehaus.jackson"
    top-level-classloader="true"
    export-all="NON_EMPTY"
    import-all="true" >
</classloading>
```

Input much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This may come from the resteasy.deployer in server/default/deployers, which contains a jackson jar.

Comment: Your hint may have helped me move forward.  Seeing new issue at the new question, linked below.  I'll come back and give you credit if this did indeed lead to progress!  Thanks..  maybe can help with new issue?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984113/jboss-classloadermanager-persistenceunitutil-incompatibleclasschangeerror